# Menu Scroll with tooltip

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my tooltip appear when I set the scroll in the menu but I can't get it to work, I need to replace the tooltip out of the box, any help would be appreciated.

Below is an example.

I tried to set the `li` to `relative` but to no avail.

I need any solution whether it's JS or CSS, in my research I saw that something like that wasn't possible but there must be a way

[image]

```js
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-search");

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
  menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
});

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { // Sidebar open when you click on the search iocn
  sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
  menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
});

// following are the code to change sidebar button(optional)
function menuBtnChange() {
  if (sidebar.classList.contains("open")) {
    closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right"); //replacing the iocns class
  } else {
    closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right", "bx-menu"); //replacing the iocns class
  }
}
```

```css
/* Google Font Link */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 78px;
  background: #11101D;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar.open {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
.sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .logo-details #btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details #btn {
  text-align: right;
}

.sidebar i {
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-list {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar li .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  /* left: calc(100% + 15px); */
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.sidebar li:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.open li .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar input {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #1d1b31;
}

.sidebar.open input {
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .bx-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar.open .bx-search:hover {
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar .bx-search:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #11101d;
}

.sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidebar.open li a .links_name {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li i {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sidebar li.profile {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 78px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.open li.profile {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar li .profile-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar li.profile .name,
.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sidebar .profile #log_out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #1d1b31;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .profile #log_out {
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar.open~.home-section {
  left: 250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

.home-section .text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 18px
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar li .tooltip {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo-details">
    <i class='bx bxl-c-plus-plus icon'></i>
    <div class="logo_name">CodingLab</div>
    <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <span class="tooltip">Search</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
        <span class="links_name">User</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">User</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-chat'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Messages</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Messages</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Analytics</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Analytics</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-folder'></i>
        <span class="links_name">File Manager</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Files</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-cart-alt'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Order</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Order</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-heart'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Saved</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Saved</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-cog'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Setting</span>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Setting</span>
    </li>
    <li class="profile">
      <div class="profile-details">
        <!--<img src="profile.jpg" alt="profileImg">-->
        <div class="name_job">
          <div class="name">Prem Shahi</div>
          <div class="job">Web designer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class='bx bx-log-out' id="log_out"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section class="home-section">
  <div class="text">Dashboard</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you want to show the tooltip on the front, so that it should be visible. Right?

Comment: that's right man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to have the tooltip element outside the scrolling container to have it fully display.

Create an element that will serve as the tooltip, perhaps just before the closing `<body>` tag:

```html
<div class="tooltip"></div>
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

Have the text that each item should have:

```html
<li data-tooltip="Search">
  <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</li>
```

Have the tooltip element be positioned and have the content of the
`data-tooltip` attribute whenever an element is hovered:

```js
const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');

const navList = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
navList.addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target }) => {
  const item = target.matches('[data-tooltip]') ? target : target.closest('[data-tooltip]');
  if (item) {
    const { top, right } = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    tooltip.style.top = `${top}px`;
    tooltip.style.left = `${right + 10}px`;
    tooltip.innerText = item.dataset.tooltip;
    tooltip.classList.add('show');
  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Hide the tooltip when no element is hovered:

```js
navList.addEventListener('mouseout', ({ target }) => {
  const item = target.matches('[data-tooltip]') ? target : target.closest('[data-tooltip]');
  if (item) {
    tooltip.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

You can then adapt this code to not function when the sidebar is open.

Full example:

```js
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-search");

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
  menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
});

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { // Sidebar open when you click on the search iocn
  sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
  menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
});

// following are the code to change sidebar button(optional)
function menuBtnChange() {
  if (sidebar.classList.contains("open")) {
    closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right"); //replacing the iocns class
  } else {
    closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right", "bx-menu"); //replacing the iocns class
  }
}

const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');

const navList = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
navList.addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target }) => {
  const item = target.matches('[data-tooltip]') ? target : target.closest('[data-tooltip]');
  if (item) {
    const { top, right } = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    tooltip.style.top = `${top}px`;
    tooltip.style.left = `${right + 10}px`;
    tooltip.innerText = item.dataset.tooltip;
    tooltip.classList.add('show');
  }
});
navList.addEventListener('mouseout', ({ target }) => {
  const item = target.matches('[data-tooltip]') ? target : target.closest('[data-tooltip]');
  if (item) {
    tooltip.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
/* Google Font Link */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 78px;
  background: #11101D;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar.open {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
.sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .logo-details #btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details #btn {
  text-align: right;
}

.sidebar i {
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-list {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar input {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #1d1b31;
}

.sidebar.open input {
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .bx-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar.open .bx-search:hover {
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar .bx-search:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #11101d;
}

.sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidebar.open li a .links_name {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li i {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sidebar li.profile {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 78px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.open li.profile {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar li .profile-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar li.profile .name,
.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sidebar .profile #log_out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #1d1b31;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .profile #log_out {
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar.open~.home-section {
  left: 250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

.home-section .text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 18px
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar li .tooltip {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo-details">
    <i class='bx bxl-c-plus-plus icon'></i>
    <div class="logo_name">CodingLab</div>
    <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li data-tooltip="Search">
      <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="Dashboard">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="User">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
        <span class="links_name">User</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="Messages">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-chat'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Messages</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="Analytics">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Analytics</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="Files">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-folder'></i>
        <span class="links_name">File Manager</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="Order">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-cart-alt'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Order</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="Saved">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-heart'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Saved</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li data-tooltip="Setting">
      <a href="#">
        <i class='bx bx-cog'></i>
        <span class="links_name">Setting</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="profile">
      <div class="profile-details">
        <!--<img src="profile.jpg" alt="profileImg">-->
        <div class="name_job">
          <div class="name">Prem Shahi</div>
          <div class="job">Web designer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class='bx bx-log-out' id="log_out"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section class="home-section">
  <div class="text">Dashboard</div>
</section>

<div class="tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: It works, but the height is lost at some point

Comment: Height of what? What do you mean by "lost"?

Comment: the height of the tooltip is lost getting too much above the element, if you scroll many times the height is lost

Comment: So you mean the top offset of tooltip element can no longer match the target element when scrolled. Yes, that would be something you'd need to account for.

Comment: I really need to add the main screen scroll so that everything lines up

Comment: not really, i moved the tooltip div above home-section and everything works perfectly thanks again